# I know $Y|Z \sim\mathbb{N}(Z,\sigma^2)$, but what is $Z|Y$?

Tags: normal-distribution, conditional-probability, conditional-expectation

Say I know the conditional distribution:

$Y|Z \sim\mathbb{N}(Z,\sigma^2)$

Now, what if I reversed this though and wanted to find the conditional distribution $Z|Y$?

From intuition I would expect the distribution to still be normal with mean of $Y$ (i.e., $Y$ is an unbiased predictor of $Z$?), but I would also think the variance is larger.

Comment: You can't really say anything about the distribution of $Z|Y$ without making some assumptions on $P(Z)$ and $P(Y)$. $Z$ could be a constant, or a die roll, or Poisson or anything you can imagine. And once you state something about $P(Z)$ and $P(Y)$ then Bayes theorem will give the answer.

Comment: This is the answer to the question, you might as well paste the same thing as an answer

Comment: @Corone Hmm, so are you saying I would need to know something like **Z ~ $\Bbb N$($\mu$,$\sigma_z^2$)** to be able to fully specify the answer?

Comment: @user3496060 More precisely, you need to know both the marginal distributions of Z and of Y.

Comment: OK, so like $f_y$(Y|Z) = $f_z$(Z|Y)$f_y(Y)\frac1{f_z(Z)}$

Comment: @user3496060 Yes, that is Bayes' theorem.

Answer (score 2):

You can't really say anything about the distribution of $Z|Y$ without making some assumptions on $P(Z)$ and $P(Y)$.  $Z$ could be a constant, or a die roll, or Poisson or anything you can imagine.  And once you state something about $P(Z)$ and $P(Y)$ then Bayes theorem will give the answer:

$P(Y|Z) = \frac{P(Z|Y)P(Y)}{P(Z)}$

In the special case where $Y$ and $Z$ are both normally distribution, then Y|Z being normal with mean proportional to $Z$ fixed variance is sufficient to conclude that $Y$ and $Z$ are **jointly** normal.  In this case:

$Z|Y  \sim N(\mu_Z + \frac{\sigma_Z \rho}{\sigma_Y} (Y-\mu_Y),(1-\rho^2)\sigma_z^2 )$

Notice that the distribution is NOT centred around $Y$ as you supposed - this means that if the Y you observe is very high above the mean of Z, then it is likely that that was due to a quite high value of Y combined with a quite high value of Z, rather than an extremely high value of Z.  This effect is the source of [regression toward the mean](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regression_toward_the_mean)